# Using a written class as a base type for an EF6 entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to EF and am still working up the learning curve.

I have 2 tables ScheduledEvent and RealizedEvent.  Obviously these are both events with similar properties, but they also have some differing properties.  A scheduled event will generate a realized event record, but a realized event does not have to be scheduled.  For simplicity, I went with 2 tables in the database.

In C#, I would like to have a base event class that both these entities inherit.

I've tried

```
public class BaseEvent
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    ... /*All overlapping properties*/
}

public partial class ScheduledEvent : BaseEvent
{ ... }
```

This generates warnings because the EF auto-generated classes do not `override` the methods and properties.

I can see in the .edmx window where I can specify a `Base Type` for the entities, but it does not allow me to choose a user written class.  I guess I could define a table with the overlapping fields, specify that in the `Base Type`, and never put data in it, but that seems silly.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using database first, you need to refactor your database too to introduce a *base class* in the database.

Here is an example of schema that has `Person`, `User` and `Contact` table. `Person` table represents a base class in the entity model.

```
create table [Person] (
   Id int identity primary key,
   Code nvarchar(max),
   FirstName nvarchar(max),
   LastName nvarchar(max)
   /* other overlapping columns */
)
create table [User] (
   Id int primary key, /* PK but also FK */
   UserName nvarchar(max),
   Password nvarchar(max),   
   foreign key(Id) references [Person](Id) on delete cascade
)
create table [Contact] (
   Id int primary key, /* PK but also FK */
   City nvarchar(max),
   PostalCode nvarchar(max),
   foreign key(Id) references [Person](Id) on delete cascade
)
```

Then you generate the entity model from database. By default the generated diagram will show you the one to zero-or-one relationship.

Then do the following in the diagram

- Delete the the one to zero-or-one relationship association
- Mark Person as Abstract
- Set User's and Contact's BaseType to Person
- Delete the Id property from User and Contact
- Open Table Mapping for User and Contact, then map the Id column to Id property
- Save

The generated `DbContext` will only have one `DbSet` of type Person.

```
public virtual DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
```

More

- [EF Designer TPH Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618292.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This really helped me understand more and push me up the curve.  I ended up using an interface so I did not have to refactor the database.  Not the best solution for maintainability, I understand.

Answer (score 0):

I created an interface for the base and then had each of the entities implement that interface.

```
public interface IEvent
{
   ...
}
public partial class ScheduledEvent : IEvent
{
   ...
}
public partial class RealizedEvent : IEvent
{
   ...
}
```

This then lets me build a collection of Events.  I can access all the shared properties and methods of IEvent and check type when needed.